# Allocating memory in C for a Fortran allocatable

Tags: c++, fortran, mixed-code, allocatable-array

We are trying to take over the memory allocation of a legacy Fortran code (+100,000 lines of code) in C++, because we are using a C library for partitioning and allocating distributed memory on a cluster. The allocatable variables are defined in modules. When we call subroutines that use these modules the index seems to be wrong (shifted by one). However, if we pass the same argument to another subroutine we get what we expect. The following simple example illustrates the issue:

hello.f95:

```
 MODULE MYMOD
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: A
    SAVE
  END MODULE

  SUBROUTINE TEST(A)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER A(*)
    PRINT *,"A(1): ",A(1)
    PRINT *,"A(2): ",A(2)
  END

  SUBROUTINE HELLO()
    USE MYMOD
    IMPLICIT NONE
    PRINT *,"A(1): ",A(1)
    PRINT *,"A(2): ",A(2)
    CALL TEST(A)
  end SUBROUTINE HELLO
```

main.cpp

```
extern "C" int* __mymod_MOD_a; // Name depends on compiler
extern "C" void hello_();      // Name depends on compiler

int main(int args, char** argv)
{
  __mymod_MOD_a = new int[10];
  for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) __mymod_MOD_a[i] = i;
  hello_();
  return 0;
}
```

We are compiling with:

```
gfortran -c hello.f95; c++ -c main.cpp; c++ main.o hello.o -o main -lgfortran;
```

Output from running ./main is

```
 A(1):            1
 A(2):            2
 A(1):            0
 A(2):            1
```

As you can see the output of A is different, though both subroutines printed A(1) and A(2). Thus, it seems that HELLO starts from A(0) and not A(1). This is probably due to that ALLOCATE has never been called directly in Fortran so that it is not aware of the bounds of A. Any work arounds?

Comment: Assumed shape arrays defined as yours `INTEGER A(*)` always start from 1, this has nothing to do with their allocation. It is the rules of argument passing that apply here.

Comment: However, do understand you are playing with fire here, I would use pointers, instead of allocatables.

Comment: Playing with fire is right :) Also, a type member with a pointer designation is also a fortran descriptor embedded within the type, but with different flags, and no dimension records at the end (since it *will* point to something that will completely define the value.

Comment: I don't think so. It will start to be funny when you will encounter a compiler with automatic left hand side reallocation at one of yours whole array operations. Happy debugging.

Comment: This happens with strings anyway and it's not funny at all :) I've looked at tonz of lines of fortran start-of-subroutine assembly to figure out why a lot of very strange things happen.

Comment: Use the iso_c_binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran array dummy arguments always start at the lower bound defined in the subroutine. Their lower bound is not retained during the call. Therefore the argument `A` in `TEST()` will always start at one. If you wish it to start from `42`, you must do:

```
INTEGER A(42:*)
```

Regarding the allocation, you are playing with fire. It is much better to use Fortran pointers for this.

```
integer, pointer :: A(:)
```

You can then set the array to point to a C buffer by

```
use iso_c_binding

call c_f_pointer(c_ptr, a, [the dimensions of the array])
```

where `c_ptr` is of `type(c_ptr)`, interoperable with `void *`, which also comes from `iso_c_binding`.

***---Edit---***
Once I see that @Max la Cour Christensen implemented what I sketched above, I see I misunderstood the output of your code. The descriptor was indeed wrong, though I didn't write anything plain wrong. The solution above still applies.

Comment: @Vladirmir F: just academic question- do you have a reliable way to assign externally created descriptors to fortran function/subroutine parameters especially for multiple dimension arrays? This would solve the problem of knowing array dimension in the fortran code.

Comment: I don't understand. If you have assumed size array, as above, no descriptor is used, just a pointer. If you have assumed shape array you pass the descriptor. If you want to rewrite the descriptor of pointer or allocatable array I don't even know it is possible in a standard way to get the address of the descriptor, but once you have it, you can edit it, but all bets are off then.

Comment: I was referring to the latter case and without iso_c_binding, when the C-side does the descriptor creation, initialization, data memory allocation, then the fortran side 'sees' this as a regular fortran array of multiple dimensions without specifying any sizes on the fortran function argument declaration. I managed to do this with ifort, *but* had to use a hack to copy the descriptor to the fortran descriptor on the stack. Goal was to run fortran code via polymorphic function interfaces that take different array shapes and sizes, but all with same data type. This isn't officially supported.

Comment: It is much better to use a preprocessor and generic interfaces. If you do not use the new TS and the official header for the assumed shape array you are on you own. I don't really see the point in these experiments, the portability, which is the strong point of Fortran,  is all gone.

Answer (score 3):

The ISO_C_BINDING "equivalent" code:

c++ code:

```
extern "C" int size;
extern "C" int* c_a;
extern "C" void hello();
int main(int args, char** argv)
{
  size = 10; 
  c_a = new int[size];
  for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) c_a[i] = i; 
  hello(); 
  return 0;
}
```

fortran code:

```
  MODULE MYMOD
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, BIND(C) :: SIZE
    TYPE (C_PTR), BIND(C) :: C_A 
    INTEGER(C_INT), POINTER :: A(:)
    SAVE
  END MODULE

  SUBROUTINE TEST(A)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER A(*)
    PRINT *,"A(1): ",A(1)
    PRINT *,"A(2): ",A(2)
  END 

  SUBROUTINE HELLO() BIND(C)
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
    USE MYMOD
    IMPLICIT NONE
    CALL C_F_POINTER(C_A,A,(/SIZE/))
    PRINT *,"A(1): ",A(1)
    PRINT *,"A(2): ",A(2)
    CALL TEST(A)
  END SUBROUTINE
```

Output:

```
A(1):            0
A(2):            1
A(1):            0
A(2):            1
```

Answer (score 1):

The internal representation of fortran arrays is very different than the one used in C/C++.

Fortran uses descriptors that start with a pointer to the array data, and followed by element type size, number of dimensions, some padding bytes, an internal 32/64 bit byte sequence indicating various flags such as pointer, target, allocatable, can be deallocated, etc. Most of these flags are not documented (at least in ifort that I have worked with), and at the end is a sequence of records, each describing the number of elements in the corresponding dimension, distance between elements, etc.

To 'see' an externally created array from fortran, you'd need to create such descriptors in C/C++, but, it does not end there because fortran also makes copies of them in the startup code of each subroutine before it gets to the first one of your statements, depending on indicators like 'in', 'out, 'inout', and other indicators used in the fortran array declaration.

Arrays within a type declared with specific sizes map well (again in ifort) to corresponding C struct members of the same type and number of elements, but pointer and allocatable type members are really descriptors in the type that need to be initialized to the correct values in all their fields so fortran can 'see' the allocatable value. This is at best tricky and dangerous, since the fortran compiler may generate copy code for arrays in undocumented ways for optimization purposes, but it needs to 'see' all the involved fortran code to do so. Anything coming outise of the fortran domain, is not known and can result in unexpected behavior.

Your best bet is to see if gfortran supports something like iso_c_binding and define such interfaces for your fortran code, and then use iso_c_binding intrinsics to map the C_PTR pointers to fortran pointers to types, arrays, etc.

You can also pass a pointer to a one-dimensional array of char, and its size, and this works for strings mostly as long as the size is passed by value as last argument (again, compiler and compiler-flag dependent).

Hope this helps.

EDIT: changed 'ifort's iso_c_binding' to 'iso_c_binding after Vladimir's comment - thanks!

Comment: Yes it is, but some of the flags are marked 'internal' and they are not. Also, there is no easy way to assign a fortran variable to an externally passed descriptor. Intel recommends to use iso_c_binding instead.

Comment: It is not ifort's iso_c_binding, it is Fortran standard! Alas, there is a whole tag here about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-iso-c-binding

Comment: As for the first comment you are right, thats' why I deleted it a few seconds after posting it.

Comment: Ok, agreed, I have worked on ifort interfacing only, never had to use fortran for any other reason, so if it is a general standard, so much the better!