# SAVE attribute needed for Fortran variables when only the C_LOC address is returned to a C program?

Tags: fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

Normally, the `SAVE` attribute is used in Fortran type declarations so that the variable retains its value at the end of a subprogram, such as described by the answers to the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2893097/7038689). However, I recently gave an example at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424572/7038689) for how a Fortran function can be written that returns *only* the C address of an allocatable character string constant to a C calling program, with the C_LOC intrinsic and other ISO_C_BINDING features of F2003. Should the `SAVE` attribute be used on the Fortran allocatable string constant to avoid potential issues?

Although I didn't use `SAVE`, the function worked as intended: the C program uses a `char*` to point at the address returned by the Fortran function, which could then be used as normal (e.g., for printing and with `strlen()`). No warnings/errors were generated. Also, this seems consistent with how I have seen `C_F_POINTER` used in the compiler docs and the examples at a related SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23891769/7038689) (that is, the target values did not have the `SAVE` attr).

Particularly since the Fortran function was called from C, it's not clear to me whether this process exhibits the expected behavior, or if it could/should have failed, or if this is a vendor-specific implementation detail. The Intel Fortran 17 documentation for `SAVE` ([here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/679841)) seems to indicate that a string constant (allocatable or not?) is saved by default, but I am not sure if I'm reading this right, or how/if this info holds up in the current context. Am I performing this process in a portable, correct manner?

---

Although I linked to the code already, here are the important bits:

```
! f_string.f90: returns the C address to an allocatable string constant:
function get_string() bind(c, name='get_string')
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    type(C_PTR) :: get_string
    character(len=:), allocatable, target :: fortstring  ! <- Include SAVE?

    fortstring = "Hello StackOverflow" // C_NULL_CHAR    ! <- NULL-terminated string constant
    get_string = C_LOC(fortstring)
end function get_string
```

```
// c_string.c: uses a char* to point at the address returned by 'get_string'
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char *get_string(void);                                  // <- Fortran fcn signature
int main(){
    char *mycharptr; 

    mycharptr = get_string();
    printf("String from Fortran: %s\n", mycharptr);
    printf("len = %d\n", strlen(mycharptr));
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled as `ifort /c f_string.f90`, `icl c_string /link f_string.obj`.

Comment: You talk about a "string constant", but `fortstring` isn't a character constant.  Yes, it's assigned a constant expression, but it remains the case that it's a variable.

Comment: @francescalus Should I say "scalar", or not bother?

Comment: It's a scalar variable, but that doesn't change much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. Save is necessary.

All allocatable entities are deallocated when the procedure exits unless they are `save`.

You can use `pointer` instead of `allocatable` and the target will not be automatically deallocated. I find it better than `save` because of possible multiple calls to the procedure.

Your program probably "worked" because although the memory block was deallocated, it was not overwritten. So the C procedure still found meaningful data, but at address it was not allowed to access. But this access is not always checked by the OS memory protection.

Comment: Ok, understood. Same as @francescalus suggested yesterday. People like you two are why I come back to SO. BTW, with `pointer` would I then need to use `c_f_pointer`? Still learning...

Comment: After experimenting: if we choose to avoid `save` it seems that the function can just return with `get_string = C_LOC(ptr_to_fortstring)`. How does that look?

Comment: If `ptr_to_fortrstring` was allocated, not just pointed by `=>`, it should work.